# How do I stream audio from the browser to a server?

Tags: javascript, html, webrtc, audio-streaming, mediarecorder

I'm trying to make a simple low*ish* latency recorder. I currently use the below code to capture and transmit audio using Socket.IO. However, only the first packet is playable because it is the only packet that contains header information.

I have also tried creating new streams every second.
It did not work because the audio would break up between recording sessions.

My question is how can I create a stream that takes input from a browser, transmits it to a server (it cannot be peer-to-peer), and can be played in another browser in near real-time. I know this is possible because apps like Discord use it.

This is the code I'm currently using. After the first packet, Chrome returns this error:
`Uncaught (in promise) DOMExecption: play() failed to load because no supported source was found.`

I've been working on this for days, please help!

```
    function schedulePacketSend() {
        if (recording) {
            navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio:true}).then(function(mediaStream) {
                const rec = RecordRTC(mediaStream, {
                    type:'audio',
                    mimeType:'audio/webm; codecs=opus',
                    recorderType:StereoAudioRecorder,
                    ondataavailable:function(e){
                        console.log('sending packet')
                        console.log(e)
                        socket.emit('audio-up', {audio:e.data, client:id})
                    },
                    timeSlice:1000
                })
                rec.startRecording()
            });
        }
    }
```

Thanks so much,

Jackson

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with RecordRTC, but this is trivial with Pion WebRTC!

[save-to-disk](https://github.com/pion/webrtc/tree/master/examples/save-to-disk) shows how you can capture the H264/Opus and save it to disk. From that point you can do w/e you want!

If you want realtime you probably want something more like [broadcast](https://github.com/pion/webrtc/tree/master/examples/broadcast) it takes the incoming media and then does a fan out to many connected peers. You can combine these two examples so you can do recording and fan out combined.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I looked a little bit into your `pion/webrtc` examples, and it looks like this project relies on a technology called STUN or TURN, which appear to be NAT routing technology.

The main problem is you need multiple IP addresses to use these protocols. I was hoping (although I'm open to other solutions) that there is some way to get raw PCM audio from the browser and be able to play that back on another client.

Comment: Raw PCM audio maybe not, but you can send Opus, or even G.711 (which is not far from raw PCM), via WebRTC: publish it to some server that can send it out for playing. On this page you can publish it to your Unreal Media Server instance: https://secure28.securewebsession.com/umediaserver.net/demos/publish.html Note that no STUN or TURN servers are required.